# How to use table output to create a new column in R

Tags: r

I have some data from which I can get the following table:

```
> table(d$Purpose, d$Good.Loan)

                    BadLoan GoodLoan
business                 34       63
car (new)                89      145
car (used)               17       86
domestic appliances       4        8
education                22       28
furniture/equipment      58      123
others                    5        7
radio/television         62      218
repairs                   8       14
retraining                1        8
```

My question is: From this output of the 'table' command, is it possible to get/create another column with "BadLoan" percentage to the total? That is how may I get a column that will have [BadLoan/(BadLoan + GoodLoan)].

Comment: Try converting to `data.frame.` first..  i..e `df1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(d$Purpose, d$Good.Loan); df1$new <- with(df1, BadLoan/(BadLoan +GoodLoan))`

Comment: Excellent! Why '.matrix' if I am going to use data.frame?

Comment: If you use it directly, it will be transformed to `long` format

Comment: Thank you akrun. Worked like magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could convert the `table` output to `data.frame` and use standard `data.frame` techniques to create a 'new' column.

```
tbl <- table(d$Purpose, d$Good.Loan)
df1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
df1$new <- with(df1, BadLoan/(BadLoan +GoodLoan))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d <- data.frame(Purpose=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE), 
      Good.Loan=sample(c('GoodLoan', 'BadLoan'),20, replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `prop.table`?

Using akrun's data generator:

```
> tbl <- table(d)
> tbl
       Good.Loan
Purpose BadLoan GoodLoan
      A       2        3
      B       1        3
      C       1        4
      D       2        3
      E       1        0

> p <- prop.table(table(d), margin=1)
> p
       Good.Loan
Purpose BadLoan GoodLoan
      A    0.40     0.60
      B    0.25     0.75
      C    0.20     0.80
      D    0.40     0.60
      E    1.00     0.00
```

As suggested by akrun, you can then append this to the table with `cbind` (and coercing the output to matrix):

```
> cbind(tbl, BadPercentage=p[,'BadLoan'])

  BadLoan GoodLoan BadPercentage
A       2        3          0.40
B       1        3          0.25
C       1        4          0.20
D       2        3          0.40
E       1        0          1.00
```

Comment: First time to hear about prop.table. Thank you for this solution.